# GLONASS Satellite Position Prediction using Almanac Data

Tags: gps, satellite

GLONASS ICD has a section named "Algorithm of calculation of satellite motion parameters using almanac". It gives the formulas in order to calculate the position and velocity of the satellite. Unfortunately I cannot get the same results as in the given example, and I don't know why. Can you suggest any other documents, sample code or calculations about this problem?

There is a paper by Wang et al. called "Predicting GLONASS Satellite Orbit Based on an Almanac Conversion Algorithm for Controlled Ionosphere Scintillation Experiment Planning". In this paper the proposed algorithm converts GLONASS almanac to GPS almanac, and the procedure that is used for GPS position calculation can be applied. However, there are undefined parameters in the given algorithm, namely `Dt^2`, `dt2`, `Ohm` and `Ohm_e` (Figure 4). Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks in advance.